# MySql from unix time gives 1 hour too much

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

Small question that is bothering me for some while now.
I'm creating a query that gets some data from my MySql database.
In that data one field is time and is saved as unix time in this case lets say `7500` is the value.

`7500` converted is `02:05` in time, but when i query my database the result is `03:05`.
i have checked the time zone of the server, MySql server and my computer and there all the same.

My Query:

```
SELECT 
timebilled AS `Ticket_Time`, 
FROM_UNIXTIME(timebilled, '%H:%i') AS `Ticket_Time_Parsed` 
FROM data_table
```

So how do i fix this?

---

EDIT:

I just solved my problem by changing the time on the Windows server 2012 from UCT+1 to UTC. 
Now the value 7500 is 02:05 for me. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: @Chronial my current timezone is EUROPE/Amsterdam

Comment: MySQL documentation for function FROM_UNIXTIME states this: *The value is expressed in the current time zone*, so value is converted to your local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you use to convert `02:05` to `7500` is not respecting your timezone as it should. `7500` is `02:05` in UTC, but you are in UTC+1. `02:05` should be converted to `3900`.

But if your are really just storing time of day and don’t want timezone conversions, I would stay away from unixtime and just store seconds till `00:00` and convert that myself.

Comment: I did not choose the unix time, i'm making a pease of software that will use the values from that database. But i now noticed that even unixtime 0 will be converted to 1:00. So what is the problem is it the software that saves the time, or the server that it is saved on?

Comment: Neither. The problem is your assumption that the values in those columns are unixtime. Unixtime is for storing absolute points in time (see Vatev’s answer), which does not seem be going on here. You should just take the db value and divide it by 60 to get hours and take the remainder of that as minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamps store points in time (e.g. 2014-04-14 13:34:22), not amounts of time (e.g. 13 hours and 12 minutes).

`FROM_UNIXTIME(7500)` gives you the datetime for your current timezone for the timestamp 7500 which in your case is `1970-01-01 03:05:00` (7500 secodnds + UTC+1 timezone).